# How to have hibernate use String.intern on attributes

Tags: java, hibernate

For some entities we need to keep loads (thousands) of detached enties permanently in memory. Many of their attributes are from a limited set of strings (though not limited enough to put it into an enumeration). Is it possible to have hibernate use String.intern for those attributes to save space?

Ideally that should work via an annotation I could put on each of those attributes, or something easily changeable, without confusing the source code too much by this implementation concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you suggest yourself, it's perfectly doable with a JPA attribute converter. You could do it on a general level by using `autoApply = true` on the converter, or you could do it on a field by field level with the `@Convert` annotation.

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class StringInternConverter implements AttributeConverter<String, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(String attribute) {
        return attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public String convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return dbData != null? dbData.intern(): null;
    }
}
```

Tested with Hibernate 5.2.10 and works like a charm!

Comment: This threw me a NullPointerException (ARRRGHHH!!!) when dbData is null. return dbData != null ? dbData.intern() : null;

Answer (score 2):

1) You can use property access for the critical properties and intern the strings in the setters:

```
public void setFoo(String foo) {
   this.foo = foo != null ? foo.intern() : null;
}
```

2) If the above solution is tedious (you may have lots of such `String` properties), then you could register a [Hibernate interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html) and intern all of the `String` fields using reflection:

```
for (Field field : getDeclaredFields(entity)) {
    if (!isStaticOrFinal(field)) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        Object value = field.get(entity);
        if (value instanceof String) {
            field.set(entity, ((String) value).intern());
        }
    }
}

private List<Field> getDeclaredFields(Object object) {
    List<Field> result = new ArrayList<Field>(Arrays.asList(object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()));
    for (Class<?> superclass = object.getClass().getSuperclass(); superclass != null; superclass = superclass.getSuperclass()) {
        result.addAll(Arrays.asList(superclass.getDeclaredFields()));
    }
    return result;
}

private boolean isStaticOrFinal(Field field) {
    return ((Modifier.STATIC | Modifier.FINAL) & field.getModifiers()) != 0;
}
```

You can execute this in the `onSave` and `onLoad` interceptor methods.

Answer (score 0):

One could probably also implement an [JPA Attribute Converter](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-how-to-implement-type-converter/) that just calls String.intern() on the attributes, and annotate the attributes with `@Convert(StringInternConverter.class)` .

Comment: I had some trouble when trying this, but don't have time to investigate. So I'm not quite sure whether this will work.